# Find Recursive definition for a $n$ characters string of ${1,2,3,4,5}$ so sum of neighbors digits won't divide by 3

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm trying to find a Recursive formula for a string to have $n$ characters and be built of the digits ${1,2,3,4,5}$ without having any occurrence where the sum of two neighbors digits can be divided by $3$. For every $n$ I want the formula to give me all the strings with $n$ length that can be built and those rules apply to them.

Comment: $a_{i}=1$ will do

Comment: And when assuming that it should contain all characters?

Comment: At least once? At least twice? At least three times?...... Is $n$ even greater than $5$? Please take some time to narrow your question down.

Comment: Hopefully I explained myself better now. I want to have all the possible combinations of such $a_n$ relating to the previous valid series - $a_{n-1}$

Comment: Relating to the previous valid series of length $n-1$? In that case say $a_n=\begin{cases} 3&\text{if } a_{n-1}\neq 3\\1&\text{if }a_{n-1}=3\end{cases}$ Actually, the $1$ could be replaced by $2,4$ or $5$ if you'd like. Is this what you're after?

Comment: But according to that, the string $12$ is also accepted.  I need to find a formula that if $a_1=2$ for exmaple, than $a_2\neq1$ and $a_2\neq4$ and could be all the other characters. And so on for all the other possibilities of $a_2$ in case $a_1$ was different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $5$ strings of length $1$ (since in those strings, the single digit has no neighbour).

Now, if a string with more than one digit ends with $1$, the previous digit must have been $1, 3$, or $4$.

If it ends with $2$, the previous digit must have been $2,3,$ or $5$.

If it ends with $3$, the previous digit could have been anything other than $3$.

Similar rules apply for $4$ and $5$. Thus you can draw up a table: $$\quad\text{ ends with}\\\begin{array}{c|ccccc}&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline 1&1&1&1&1&1\\2&3&3&4&3&3\\3\end{array}$$

The first number in the new row must be $3+4+3=10$ because you add the last row's numbers from columns $1,3,$ and $4$.

If you continue the table, a pattern will appear from which you can derive a formula.

Comment: That's a good direction, though I filled it up more my brain is on fire, and no definition found yet

Comment: You can reduce the table to two columns. If you look more closely, you can reduce the table to just one column.

Comment: I know it is probably something of the shape of $a_{n}=4a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ yet I can't really see it unfortunately

Comment: Call the final number in the outer columns $x$, and in the middle column $y$. Then you have $x=2x'+y'$ and $y=4x'$ where $'$ means *previous*.

Comment: Substitute $y'=4x''$ into the first equation and you're done.

Comment: The expression $x=2x'+4x''$ is exactly equivalent to $a_n=2a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}$. Remember that the sum of each row is a linear combination, so it obeys the same recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be the number of valid strings with $n$ characters, and

let $c_n$ be the number of valid strings with $n$ characters which end with a $3$.

Then $c_{n+1}=a_n-c_n\;$ (since a valid  string of length $n+1$ which ends in a $3$ is preceded by any valid string ${\hspace 1.5 in}$of length $n$ which does not end in a $3$),

and $a_{n+1}=3a_n+c_n\;$ (since a valid string of length $n$ has 3 possibilities for the next digit, except in the case ${\hspace 1.5 in}$when the last digit is a 3, when there are 4 possibilities);

so substituting $c_n=a_{n+1}-3a_n$ in the first equation gives

$\hspace{.25 in}a_{n+2}-3a_{n+1}=a_n-(a_{n+1}-3a_n)$ or

$\hspace{.25 in}\color{blue}{a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+4a_n}$.